# How to submit a form in react-materialize?

Tags: reactjs

GoodDay. How do I submit a form in react-materialize. While using normal jsx i usually do something like this `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> </form>`. But in react-materialized like here https://react-materialize.github.io/#/forms I cant find anything like  component. So, where do I need to attach my onSubmit handler

Comment: What you want to do exactly? Posting the form to a server side action or want to make a REST api call?

Comment: You should write handleSubmit() method in your  jsx file. For more information post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can treat those inputs like you would any other inputs, wrap them in a `<form>` and listen for `onSubmit` event. Here's a minimal working example:

```
<form
    onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.handleSubmit()
    }}
>
    <Row>
        <Input
            s={6}
            label="First Name"
        />
        <Button>hello</Button>
    </Row>
</form>
```

Please note a few things:

- I'm doing a `e.preventDefault()`, to stop the form from refreshing the page. Another way of doing this would be to pass the event like:

`<form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>`

And then prevent it inside the `handleSubmit` function like so:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // other code
}
```

- I'm not at all checking the input values here. You can attach a `onChange` event listener to all inputs, and make them update the state on every input change. Your `handleSubmit` could then read input values from the state when you submit the form.

`<Input s={6} label="First Name" onChange={e => this.setState({inputValue: e.currentTarget.value})} />`

In which case, your `handleSubmit` function can access the value from `this.state.inputValue`.

This is completely unrelated to materialize, and how you would normally handle a form. There doesn't seem to a specific `<Form>` component they provide, so you can just use a basic html element with some modifications.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I just was confused by the absence of <Form /> component.